# Is "I better focus" present or past tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

Example sentence (past tense narration):

> **I better focus on the external world, especially on the front door waiting for me ahead.** What would I find on the other side? Reality,
>   probably.

Is "I better focus" present tense (hence out of place in past tense narration). Or can be both present and past tense?

If it's present tense by nature, what's the past tense alternative?

Comment: I would consider "You better" appropriate for informal speech only. Basically it is omitting the "'d", or it is just not heard in fast speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formally correct "standard" version is

> I had better focus on X...
>
> You'd better have that clunking sound checked out by a mechanic. It sounds like your wheel-bearing is shot.

with a backshift of tense reflecting that this is a form of *irrealis* statement: the better thing to do (which the speaker in the first example has not  done and is not doing yet) is to focus on X, or, in the second example, to have a mechanic examine the car.

But many speakers say "I better focus...".

> You better give me your lunch money, punk.
>
> It's late. We better get going.

Comment: Thanks. So it would be okay to say "I better" in a novel, because it's not formal writting?

Comment: From my wheel-bearing example, you can see that "You'd better" (with contracted "You had") is already not formal in register. It's neutral and conversational.  "You better" or "I better" is heard most often in milieus in which the general educational level is somewhat below average.